# GoogleAuthUtil : getting IO Exception (Network error)

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to get token using GoogleAuthUtil so that I could verify the request at backend.

I simply used a AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent()

```
private void pickUserAccount() {
    String[] accountTypes = new String[]{"com.google"};
    Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
            accountTypes, false, null, null, null, null);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);

}
```

this is onActivityResult

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mEmail = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            new VerifyToken().execute(mEmail);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You need to select account.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

AsyncTask :

```
class VerifyToken extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String>{
    String mScope = "audience:server:client_id:X";
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try{
            String token =  GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), strings[0] ,mScope );
```

This is error log:
[image]